# How to add plus minus button on Input Quantity box Woocommerce?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I want ot add + and - button after and before the quantity input on single product page? how is this possible to add using standard method lets say using hooks and fitler?

Comment: I don't want any plugin to get this functionality done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below code snippet will display Plus & Minus Quantity Buttons @ WooCommerce Single Product Page. [Reference](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-plus-minus-buttons-to-add-to-cart-quantity-input/)

```
/**
 * @snippet       Plus Minus Quantity Buttons @ WooCommerce Single Product Page
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=90052
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.5.1
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */

// -------------
// 1. Show Buttons

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'bbloomer_display_quantity_plus' );

function bbloomer_display_quantity_plus() {
   echo '<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'bbloomer_display_quantity_minus' );

function bbloomer_display_quantity_minus() {
   echo '<button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>';
}

// -------------
// 2. Trigger jQuery script

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bbloomer_add_cart_quantity_plus_minus' );

function bbloomer_add_cart_quantity_plus_minus() {
   // Only run this on the single product page
   if ( ! is_product() ) return;
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function($){   

         $('form.cart').on( 'click', 'button.plus, button.minus', function() {

            // Get current quantity values
            var qty = $( this ).closest( 'form.cart' ).find( '.qty' );
            var val   = parseFloat(qty.val());
            var max = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'max' ));
            var min = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'min' ));
            var step = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'step' ));

            // Change the value if plus or minus
            if ( $( this ).is( '.plus' ) ) {
               if ( max && ( max <= val ) ) {
                  qty.val( max );
               } else {
                  qty.val( val + step );
               }
            } else {
               if ( min && ( min >= val ) ) {
                  qty.val( min );
               } else if ( val > 1 ) {
                  qty.val( val - step );
               }
            }

         });

      });

      </script>
   <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks Momin. It works great

Comment: The one who have voted negative can let me know what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: I have not voted negative.